# Ошибка запроса

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Привет.
Такая проблема, при таком коде:

```
function save_order(){
    global $connection;
    $query = "INSERT INTO orders (`customer_id`, `date`, `dostavka_id`, `prim`)
                VALUES ($customer_id, NOW(), $dostavka_id, '$prim')";
    mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == -1){
        // если не получилось сохранить заказ - удаляем заказчика
        mysqli_query("DELETE FROM customers
                        WHERE customer_id = $customer_id AND login = ''");
        return false;
    }
    $order_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection); // ID сохраненного заказа

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $goods_id => $value){
        $val .= "($order_id, $goods_id, {$value['qty']}),";    
    }
    $val = substr($val, 0, -1); // удаляем последнюю запятую

    $query = "INSERT INTO zakaz_tovar (orders_id, goods_id, quantity)
                VALUES $val";
    mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == -1){
        // если не выгрузился заказа - удаляем заказчика (customers) и заказ (orders)
        mysqli_query("DELETE FROM orders WHERE order_id = $order_id");
        mysqli_query("DELETE FROM customers
                        WHERE customer_id = $customer_id AND login = ''");
        return false;
    }

    // если заказ выгрузился
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    unset($_SESSION['total_sum']);
    unset($_SESSION['total_quantity']);
    $_SESSION['order']['res'] = "<div class='success'>Спасибо за Ваш заказ.</div>";
    return true;
}
```

Выходит ошибка:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' NOW(), , '')' at line 2**

То есть эта функция самостоятельного формирования даты и времени устарела? Как решить, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нужно посмотреть, чему равна переменная $query перед запросом, тогда и ошибку можно будет увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Alextrue](/users/23784/alextrue)](/users/23784/alextrue), Ошибка связана скорее всего с тем, что в `$prim` есть кавычки. Распечатайте текст запроса, посчитайте количество кавычек и запятых. Чтоб исправить и никогда больше не ошибаться, пользуйтесь [параметрами](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 0):

`VALUES ($customer_id, NOW(), $dostavka_id, '$prim')`

Тут и слепой увидит синтаксические ошибки :)

**Обновление**

[[@Alextrue](/users/23784/alextrue)](/users/23784/alextrue) так попробуй, потому что запрос рабочий :)

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`customer_id`, `date`, `dostavka_id`, `prim`) VALUES ({$customer_id}, NOW(), {$dostavka_id}, '{$prim}')
```

Comment: @Bastian, Я не вижу, что не так?

Comment: date это название поля в таблице, а NOW() формирует время и дату заказа

Comment: @Bastian, не помогло.(

Comment: @Alextrue, ну, тогда это странно, :) так как я проверил запрос.

Comment: @Bastian, А если убрать date и NOW(), то выходит: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , '')' at line 2

Comment: @Alextrue помести переменные в кавычки согласно синтаксису php.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вообще вставлять значение NOW()? Поставь DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP полю date.

Answer (score 0):

Делается дамп запроса (то есть что там сгенерилось, выводится в консоль или прямо на страницу), дамп копируется в буфер, вставляется из буфера в, скажем, phpMyAdmin, и там с помощью подсветки синтаксиса довольно легко можно найти косяки синтаксиса.